# Convert HEX to ANSI in PHP

Tags: php, hex, ansi

I'm coding a kind of hexadecimal viewer, where the user inputs the executable and the page returns the hex dump and the representation in ANSI beside. (actually i don't know why use ANSI, but the Hex Editor that i'm using returns the result using this)

Something like this:

[image]

But my code returns this:

[image]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i tryed another codes, and it returned all the charecters, but i need to make that some bytes return a dot ".", as you can see in the print.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php

function hex2str($hex) {
    $str = '';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2) $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2)));
    return $str;
} // i found this function on internet to convert HEX to String

$nome = "apateDNS.exe";//the name of the file
$arquivo = fopen($nome, "r");
$read = fread($arquivo,filesize($nome));
$hex = bin2hex($read);// return the hex of the binary
$hehe = chunk_split(strtoupper($hex), 2, " ");// split the hex each 2 bytes
$haha = str_split($hehe, 48); //split the hex each 48 characters (32 bytes + 16 blank spaces)
foreach($haha as $linha => $i){
    echo "0000000".dechex($linha*16);
    echo " ".$i." ".hex2str($i)."<br>";
}
?>
```

**Solved**: I forgot to delete the blank spaces in the function...

```
$hex = str_replace(" ", "", $hex);
```

Comment: You have to replace non printable characters with a dot:

Comment: You could also replace `echo "0000000".dechex($linha*16);` with `echo sprintf( '%08X', $linha*16 );`. It is prettier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hex2str($hex) {
    $str = '';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2) {
        $decValue = hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2));
        if($decValue < 32) {
            $str .= '.';
        } else {
            $str .= chr($decValue);
        }
    }
        return $str;
}
```

To produce a table of all hex codes and their translation use this code:

```
for($x = 0; $x < 16; $x++) {
    $bin = $txt = array();
    for($y = 0; $y < 16; $y++) {        
        $num = dechex($x * 16 + $y);
        if(strlen($num) == 1) $num = '0' . $num;
        $bin[] = $num;
        $txt[] = hex2str($num);

    }
    echo (implode(' ',$bin) . '     ' . implode(' ',$txt)) . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Nice, max, this function replaced the non printable characters to a dot, but it's not like the first screenshot, some bytes weren't converted. The "5A" should be a "Z", but it became a dot... And there are some interrogations yet. Any other tip? Thxxx guys

Comment: I have added some code to produce a table of all hex codes and their char representation. Could you provide a screenshot of the output?

Comment: I forgot to delete the blank spaces in the function... That's why it didn't work. Here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/93z9qw